# Expression unexpectedly not evaluating to a numerical value

Tags: core-language, units

When I calculate the below, I get an unexpected output, not giving me the density, but rather a value M * ..

```
Clear["Global`*"] ;
R = 
  UnitConvert[
     Quantity[2.7828000000000004`*^7, "Meters"], 
     "JupiterEquatorialRadius"];
i == 1.5135776449524154`; (*rad*)
M == Quantity[0.080 , "JupiterMass"]/Sin[1.5135776449524154] ;
ρ == M/(4 π R^3) // N
```

The out put is then:

```
ρ == M (Quantity[1.34932, 1/("JupiterEquatorialRadius")^3])
```

Why is `M` not given a numerical value?

Comment: Omittng semicolon, one sees `M == Quantity[0.0801311, "JupiterMass"]`. This is not a number so `N` does not work.

Comment: why is this not considered a number, and why does it not even work when I put `UnitConvert[M/(4 \[Pi] R^3), "g/cm^3"]`. What else can I do?

Comment: You are using `Equal` ( = = ) where you should be using `Set` ( = ) . `Equal` is the boolean operator; `Set` is the assignment operator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

R = UnitConvert[Quantity[2.7828000000000004`*^7, "Meters"], 
   "JupiterEquatorialRadius"];

i = 1.5135776449524154`;(*rad*)
```

You are using [`Equal`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Equal.html) where you apparently mean to use [`Set`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Set.html)

```
M = Quantity[0.080, "JupiterMass"]/Sin[i];
```

If you want the result using "JupiterEquatorialRadius" use

```
ρ = UnitConvert[M]/(4 π R^3)

(* Quantity[2.05231*10^26, ("Kilograms")/("JupiterEquatorialRadius")^3] *)
```

If not, use

```
ρ = M/(4 π R^3) // UnitConvert

(* Quantity[561.657, ("Kilograms")/("Meters")^3] *)
```